# Scrollviewer in a complicated grid/datagrid scenario not working correctly

Tags: wpf, datagrid, tabs, scrollviewer

I have looked at every related answer I can find I have tried most of the offered solutions but nothing is working. First the visual...
[image: Grid of Datagrids]

The inner TabControl and the ScrollViewer are added in code (there will be multiple tabs), each red rectangle represents a row in a GRID. The first and last rows just contain TextBlocks and the mousewheel scrolls the scrollviewer when over those rows. The inner rows contain DataGrids and they are consuming the scroll/mousewheel event (I assume). Everything on the Daily Objectives tab is a usercontrol that is populated based on a viewmodel, The rows are static accept for scores and comments.
I can't get the scrollviewer to work while over the datagrids. I'll post all the XAML for the UserControl but it is not very enlightening. I have tried numerous solutions and I have a similar situation on another tab that does work but the solution there doesn't work here.

```
<UserControl x:Class="EMSTrainingApp.UserControls.DailyScoresControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         MinHeight="800" MinWidth="1000" Width="Auto" Background="White" BorderThickness=".5" BorderBrush="DarkGray">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="180"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="110"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="130"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="153"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="105"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="125"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Height="180">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,.5" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DailyScoreTitle, FallbackValue=Daily Objectives for 09/22/2023}" Background="LightSteelBlue" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="Navy" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20" />
        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0,0,0,.5" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
            <TextBlock Text="Expose the new team member to clinical operations in all aspects related to patient care respective to their level of certification." 
                               TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="Navy" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20"/>
        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Row="2" BorderThickness="0,0,0,.5" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
            <TextBlock Text="The new team member is expected to operate the ambulance at all times when not functioning as a patient care attendant or completing documentation related to patient care." 
                               Background="LightSteelBlue" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="Navy" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20"/>
        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Row="3" BorderThickness="0,0,0,.5" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
            <TextBlock Text="The Preceptor should instruct and coach the new teammate in a variety of general operations, computer systems, clinical operations, vehicle operations, and check for understanding." 
                               TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="Navy" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20"/>
        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Row="4" BorderThickness="0,0,0,.5" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
            <TextBlock Text="Review all aspects of the previous shifts with orientee and complete competencies to prepare Orientee as a competent clinician." 
                               Background="LightSteelBlue" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="Navy" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20"/>
        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Row="5" BorderThickness="0,0,0,.5" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
            <TextBlock Text="As a Third Rider the Orientee is expected to operate as a clinician relative to their skill level with supervision of the FTO. During Second Rides, the Orientee is considered an independent clinician with FTO supervision." 
                               TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="Navy" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20"/>
        </Border>

        <Grid Grid.Row="6" Height="60">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="510"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="1 = Unsatisfactory, 3 or 5 Satisfactory, 7&#x0a;Exceeds, N.O. - Not Observed/Not Applicable" 
                                   Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" TextAlignment="Center" Background="LightGray" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" Padding="0,8,0,0"/>

            <TextBox Text="Any rating &lt; 3 must have written justification in the appropriate comments field. The expectation is that a DOR is completed at the end of each orientee's shift and reviewed with the FTO. The ONLY exception is in regards to excessive call volume in which a paper form could be completed and turned into the training office within 1 calendar day." 
                                  Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" TextAlignment="Center" Background="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" IsReadOnly="True"
                                  Foreground="Black" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="5,0,5,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical" Height="110">

        <TextBlock Text="Professionalism" Background="Navy" Foreground="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold" Height="22" Padding="0,1,0,0"/>

        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ProfessionalismObjectives}" PreviewMouseWheel="DataGrid_PreviewMouseWheel"
                                            Height="100" Width="Auto" SelectionMode="Single"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
                                            SelectionUnit="FullRow"  Background="White" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                                            GridLinesVisibility="All" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AlternationCount="2" >

            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSteelBlue"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>

            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" >

                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cyan"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>

            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="22"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCyan"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>

            <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Objective/Competency" Width="350" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextAlignment="Left" Padding="0,0,5,0"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Score" Width="80">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Score}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Avr" Width="80">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding AVR}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="FTO Comments" MinWidth="250" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Comments}" TextAlignment="Left" Padding="0,0,5,0" Background="LightSteelBlue"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <!--padding-->
                <!--<DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="30"/>-->
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical" Height="130">
        <TextBlock Text="Crew Resource Management" Background="Navy" Foreground="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                           TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold" Height="20" Padding="0,1,0,0"/>

        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CrewResourceObjectives}"  PreviewMouseWheel="DataGrid_PreviewMouseWheel"
                                            Height="125" Width="Auto" SelectionMode="Single"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                                            SelectionUnit="Cell"  Background="White" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"
                                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" GridLinesVisibility="All"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AlternationCount="2" >

            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSteelBlue"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>

            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" >

                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cyan"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>

            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="22"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCyan"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>

            <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Objective/Competency" MinWidth="350" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextAlignment="Left" Padding="0,0,5,0"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Score" MinWidth="80">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Score}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Avr" MinWidth="80">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding AVR}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="FTO Comments" MinWidth="250" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Comments}" TextAlignment="Left" Padding="0,0,5,0" Background="LightSteelBlue"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <!--padding-->
                <!--<DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="30"/>-->
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Vertical" Height="153">
        <TextBlock Text="Guidelines and Job Knowledge" Background="Navy" Foreground="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                           TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold" Height="20" Padding="0,1,0,0"/>

        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GuidelineObjectives}"  PreviewMouseWheel="DataGrid_PreviewMouseWheel"
                                        Height="150" Width="Auto" SelectionMode="Single"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                                        SelectionUnit="Cell"  Background="White" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True"
                                        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" GridLinesVisibility="All"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AlternationCount="2" >

            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSteelBlue"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>

            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" >

                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cyan"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>

            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="22"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCyan"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>

            <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Objective/Competency" MinWidth="350" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextAlignment="Left" Padding="0,0,5,0"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Score" MinWidth="80">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Score}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Avr" MinWidth="80">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding AVR}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="FTO Comments" MinWidth="250" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Comments}" TextAlignment="Left" Padding="0,0,5,0" Background="LightSteelBlue"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <!--padding-->
                <!--<DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="30"/>-->
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="4" Orientation="Vertical" Height="105">
        <TextBlock Text="Vehicle Operations" Background="Navy" Foreground="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                           TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold" Height="20" Padding="0,1,0,0"/>

        <DataGrid Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding VehicleObjectives}" PreviewMouseWheel="DataGrid_PreviewMouseWheel"
                                        Height="85" Width="Auto" SelectionMode="Single"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                                        SelectionUnit="Cell"  Background="White" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True"
                                        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" GridLinesVisibility="All"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AlternationCount="2" >

            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSteelBlue"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>

            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" >

                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cyan"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>

            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="22"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCyan"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>

            <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Objective/Competency" MinWidth="350" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextAlignment="Left" Padding="0,0,5,0"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Score" MinWidth="80">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Score}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Avr" MinWidth="80">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding AVR}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="FTO Comments" MinWidth="250" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Comments}" TextAlignment="Left" Padding="0,0,5,0" Background="LightSteelBlue"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <!--padding-->
                <!--<DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="30"/>-->
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid Grid.Row="5" MaxHeight="125"  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="FTO Additional Comments (Be Specific)" Background="Navy" Foreground="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                           TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold" Height="20" Padding="0,1,0,0"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Background="LightSteelBlue"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined a few answers and found a solution. I added the same handler to each of the grids for the PreviewMouseWheel and added the method FindVisualAncestorOfType to a static class I already had.

```
public static T FindVisualAncestorOfType<T>(this DependencyObject Elt) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        for (DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(Elt);
            parent != null; parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent))
        {
            T result = parent as T;
            if (result != null)
                return result;
        }
        return null;
    }


private void DataGrid_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        var dg = sender as DataGrid;
        ScrollViewer sv=dg.FindVisualAncestorOfType<ScrollViewer>();
        sv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(sv.VerticalOffset - e.Delta);
    }
```